# No option to create a new website in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

If I run `inetmgr` I can see the IIS MMC and I can also see an `IIS Admin` service on my computer. Do both of these things mean that IIS is installed?

In the IIS management console, I can only see Website and FTP site folders with nothing in them. When I right click on an option, the only options are refresh and help.

Why can't I find an option to create a new website?

Comment: I'm thinking that you believe "IIS" to be come monolithic package that is either "installed" or not. That is not the case, IIS has many components which can each be installed. What particular part or functionality are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the OS..
If it's Windows 2003, you can check the components installed in your server from control panel > programs > Windows componentes (or something like that..)
If it's Windows 2008, you can check them from Server Manager -> Roles and Features.

Regards!